# can't access to servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

i create a servlet in locale with eclipse and I tested in locale in localhost, I can call it and obtain the right answer.

I need to put it in a server and call it from a form when I submit it. 
But if I use the same call method I used in local I obtain error 404.

I export my package in a .jar and I put it under WEB-INF/lib

the pieces I write in the web.xml are the same and I cant't solve the problem.

When I call it in localhost i use "http://localhost:8080/ServletRecaptcha/CheckRecaptchaServlet" and I obtain the right question.

When I call it in the my web page instead I use a form 
    < form id="form" action="/ServletRecaptcha/CheckRecaptchaServlet" method="post">...< /form>

But I obtain 404.

This is the code i insert in my web.xml

```
       <servlet-name>ServletRecaptcha</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>servlet.CheckRecaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ServletRecaptcha</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/CheckRecaptchaServlet</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the form action to the URL-Pattern action="CheckRecaptchaServlet" you defined in your servlet-mapping?